# Flow symbol is not googleable and I do not see it anywhere in the documentation (less than and then a colon - "<:")

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

I am trying to understand the babel codebase and I ran into this symbol "<:" used with interfaces. Here is an example:

```
interface BooleanLiteral <: Literal {
  type: "BooleanLiteral";
  value: boolean;
}
```

This is a very hard thing to google for, and after reading most nearly all of the Flow documentation, I still cannot find a description of this symbol. Does anybody know?

(You can find plenty more examples here: [babel spec docs](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-parser/ast/spec.md#node-objects))

Comment: Good questions, I'm not a Flow user, I guess it is something that is specific for AST node type specification...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax used in Babel's AST documentation just a made-up [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), it is not Flowtype. Babel inherited it from [ESTree](https://github.com/estree/estree#ast-descriptor-syntax).

```
interface BooleanLiteral <: Literal {}
```

essentially declares a new type `BooleanLiteral` that extends `Literal`.